# XML attributes with single quotes using XML R package on Tripadvisor

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I have an XPath query that looks like this, with both single and double quotes. How do I escape the apostrophe properly so that the query works?

I tried:

```
rating<- getNodeSet(doc1,"//*[(@id = "taplc_location_reviews_list_apd_0")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ui_bubble_rating", " " ))]"
```

How can I use this Xpath so that I'm able to scrape rating from Tripadvisor?

It's giving an error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "rating<- getNodeSet(doc1,"//*[(@id = "taplc_location_reviews_list_apd_0"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the double quotes inside the xpath to single quotes (but leave the double quotes around the xpath), like so:

```
rating<- getNodeSet(doc1,"//[(@id = 'taplc_location_reviews_list_apd_0')]//[contains(concat( ' ', @class, ' ' ), concat( ' ', 'ui_bubble_rating', ' ' ))]"
```